# How does Codius differ from Ethereum?

Tags: contract-design, oracles

Codius is one of smart contract platforms by Ripple which project is unfortunately suspended.

What did they try to do with Codius?
How does it differ from Ethereum?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Codius is/was a offchain smart oracle platform. These are basically sandboxed virtual machines running Google’s Native Client. The sandboxed VMs can be paid to run untrusted native code and to report the results to some underlying consensus system (ethereum, bitcoin, ripple) signing these transactions. You then choose to trust the results provided by a super majority of these oracles. The idea is that these oracles are unlikely to collude and thus the majority result can be trusted.