# Comparing Ripple and Ethereum

Tags: blockchain

What advantages and disadvantages does Ripple have over Ethereum?

Comment: Hyperledger and IBM are answered here: http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1446/what-advantages-and-disadvantages-does-open-blockchain-have-over-ethereum  I suggest editing this question to narrow down to Ripple.

Comment: Related: http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2121/how-does-codius-differ-from-ethereum